# Python logging issues from multiple modules

Tags: python, singleton, logging

I have 3 python modules.

```
LogManager.py
Runner.py
Other.py
```

`Runner.py` is the first main module in the chain of events, and from that module functions inside `Other.py` are called.

So, inside `Runner.py` I have a function call to the `LogManager.py`

```
logger = LogManager.get_log()
```

and from there, I can make simple logs, e.g. `logger.critical("OHNOES")`

What I WANT the `get_log` function to do, is something similar to a singleton pattern, where if the logger has not been set up, it will set up the logger and return it. Else, it will just return the logger.

Contents of LogManager.py:

```
import logging

def get_log():
    logger = logging.getLogger('PyPro')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create file handler which logs even debug messages
    fh = logging.FileHandler('pypro.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create console handler with a higher log level
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    # create formatter and add it to the handlers
    fhFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    chFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(filename)s - Line: %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(fhFormatter)
    ch.setFormatter(chFormatter)

    # add the handlers to logger
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    logger.info("-----------------------------------")
    logger.info("Log system successfully initialised")
    logger.info("-----------------------------------")

    return logger
```

As you can see, LogManager.get_log() will attempt to set up a log each time it is called. Really, I am a bit confused as to exactly what is happening...

Runner.py calls the get_log function in it's main method.
Other.py calls the get_log in the global scope (right after imports, not in any function)

The result is that all of the logs I make are logged twice, as handlers are made twice for the logger.

What is the simplest way that I am missing to make the get_log function to return an instance of the same log elsewise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `logging` module already implements a singleton pattern for you - when you call `logger.getLogger(name)`, it will create the logger if it hasn't done so already and return it. Although it's not *exactly* what you're asking for, I would suggest just renaming `get_log()` to `setup_log()`, since that's what it does. Then you can just call `setup_log()` once, at the beginning of your code. Afterwards, when you actually need the logger, just use `logging.getLogger()` and it will return the already-configured logger.

Comment: The problem unfortunately is that I've been using the `Other.py` main function as a validation test which I would like to be able to do. I could not do that if I simply called logging.getLogger(), as if I was doing said validation test, I would not have setup the log (the log would be setup in Runner.py)