# Python singleton logging not working properly - Duplicate log statements in the file

Tags: python, logging, singleton

I am trying to put logging in python python project. For that, I have written a method called `get_logger` in my common.py that returns the logger.

```
import logging
def get_logger(name='app'):
    log_config = config.LOG_CONFIG
    logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    return logger
```

Note that the log configurations are put in `config.LOG_CONFIG`

```
LOG_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,  # this fixes the problem

    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
        # more formatters
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'filename': '%s/%s' % (_cwd, '../logs/app/logging.log'),
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'when': 'midnight',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # Works for
        # 1. application logs (flask) and
        # 2. all other logs where below logger name is passed to getLogger
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
        # For all the remaining logs
        # Important: Don't include for production??
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

I have two modules

- base.py
- sf_apis.py

a class from sf_apis.py extends a class from base.py. I have called get_logger in base.py.

**base.py**

```
from common import get_logger
log = get_logger()

class Base:

    // .. some code ..
```

Then just called `getLogger` from `logging` to get that logger in sf_apis.py

**sf_apis.py**

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('app')

class SfBulk(Base):

    // .. some code ..
```

But when my another module called `sync_data.py` that runs by calling some methods from `sf_apis.py`, I see duplicate log statements in my log

```
2015-11-04 13:05:58,605 [    INFO] app: close_the_job :: job id = 75090000003sf4YAAQ
2015-11-04 13:05:58,605 [    INFO] app: close_the_job :: job id = 75090000003sf4YAAQ
```

I read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341538/python-logging-issues-from-multiple-modules) that

> The logging module already implements a singleton pattern

so I didn't go and create a singleton Logger class (There are many examples on internet)

What did I miss? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python loggers have hierarchical structure. You've created two: `'app'` and `''`. By convention, hierarchy is defined as dot-separated path to the module. In a particular case, empty string logger becomes a parent for all other first-level loggers. Specifically, `''` is parent of `'app'`.

Now you set `propagate = True` for `'app'` logger. It means that a message sent to this logger would be also propagated to its parent, i.e. `''`. That's how you have duplicated messages.

You can either set `propagate = False` to `'app'` logger or set another file handler for `''` logger such that the messages would be still duplicated, but in different files.

Comment: Yep. That's the issue. Upvoted and accepted your answer. One more thing, instead of calling `logging.getLogger`, what if I call my `get_logger` in `sf_api.py`. Because I want my every module to be independent.

Comment: Sure, you can. I'd also suggest you to refactor `get_logger` such that `dictConfig` is called only once when `get_logger` is called the first time

Comment: That's much better then. Any hint on how to call `dictConfig` only once?

Comment: You can do something like this:
`__logging_configured = False`
    `def get_logger(name='app'):`
        `global __logging_configured`
        `if not __logging_configured:`
            `logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)`
            `__logging_configured = True`
        `logger = logging.getLogger(name)`
        `return logger`. I'm sorry, there's no way to have multiline code section in the comments